# put coldfusion query result into javascript array as a javascript object (google maps)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, coldfusion

I have a database of latitude and longitude values for state borders which I am using to draw polygons of the state on a map.

I am querying the database using coldfusion and I want the value to be returned like this
example

"NY" :[new google.maps.LatLng(1,2), new google.maps.LatLng(3,4), new google.maps.LatLng(5,6)]

for every state that is requested and then put it in a javascript array of stateBorders

see code below:

```
<cfquery datasource="source" name="states">
select * from state_lat_long where stateid order by stateid, orderid
</cfquery>


var stateBorder={};//declare array to hold the state latitude and longitude values

//need to take this whole thing and put it into array, then loop through the array
<cfoutput query="states" group="stateid">
    var #states.stateid# = [
    "#states.stateid#":[
    <cfset count=0>
    <cfoutput> <cfif count>, </cfif>new google.maps.LatLng    (#states.latitude#,#states.longitude#)<cfset count=count +1></cfoutput>
    ]
    ];
    stateBorder.push(states.stateid);
</cfoutput>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're asking?  I don't see a question in there anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to craete the datas you need in cf and then convert it into json format and pass i to js.
This is untested but can give you an idea:

```
<cfquery datasource="source" name="states">
select * from state_lat_long where stateid order by stateid, orderid
</cfquery>

<cfset arr = ArrayNew(1)>

<cfoutput query="states">

    <cfset state = {#stateid# = 'new google.maps.LatLng(#states.latitude#,#states.longitude#)'}>
    <cfset arrayAppend(arr,state)>

</cfoutput>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var states = <cfoutput>#serializeJson(arr)#</cfoutput>; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For converting query object into JS object, there's `ToScript()`.  However, if you need it in a specific JS object format, you've got to construct the struct carefully yourself, then maybe use `SerializeJSON()` to get the JSON representation of your object literal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the variables you want in coldfusion:

   `<cfset stateID = #states.stateid#>`
2. Convert the CF variable into javascript variable:

   `var toScript(stateID, "stateIDvar");`

Where stateID is the name of the CF variable and stateIDvar will be the javascript name. And then insert the points into your javascript array in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar answer to @Andrea Campolonghi's, this iterates through the column list, creating a struct that can then be json encoded (in case you dont care for how serializeJSON encodes queries with separate arrays for columnlist and data

```
//this is the query
        rc.qAllocations=getmodel("somemodel").getQuery();

        returnArray = ArrayNew(1);

var col2List = rc.qAllocations.Columnlist;      
for (i=1; i<= rc.qAllocations.recordcount; i++) {
Struct = StructNew();
for (col2=1; col2 <= ListLen(col2List); col2++) {
    var stable2 = LCase(listGetAt(col2List, col2));;
        Struct[stable2] = #rc.qAllocations[stable2][i]#;
        ArrayAppend(returnArray,Struct);
    }
}
rc.json = serializeJson(returnArray);
```